# Selenium/Python/Chrome: Browser Chrome can`t create directory 'Selenium'

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Application that normally works on the PC under this User (Administrator) suddenly begins to launch Windows alarm-window: "Browser Google Chrome can't execute read and write operations in directory 'selenium'."
(But after 'Cancel' this alarm - app works Ok - it get the page in Chrome, and handles it normally).

But the app opens different pages in the new Chrome-window many-many times, and i can`t to sit and press 'Cancel' all the time )))

Aditionaly, this code normally work on enother PC in the remote workplace.

Code:

````
```python
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
...
        options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

        options.add_argument("user-data-dir=selenium")
        options.add_argument("--remote-debugging-port=9222")

        driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(), options=options)
        
        try:
            driver.get(url) 
            ...
```
````